# How to add attributes for a textbox column in gridview ? vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

When a user click in my text box i want to put value OK in text box, when he action double click i want to punt NOK in textbox. I know that is possible with attributes but how?

I have my column in grid view like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Rating" >
    < ItemTemplate >
        < asp:TextBox ID = "BOX_Rating" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Rating") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I added values into my textbox like this (and to my table):

```
dr = dt.NewRow()
dr("Item_number") = Paragraphorder
dr("Station") = ActivityResource
dr("Verified_characteristic") = Description
dr("Measurement_techinque") = ActivityName
dr("Specification") = RequirementNom
dr("Frequency") = Frequency
dr("Responsible_person") = "VMO"
dr("Rating") = "OK"
dr("Result_1") = "OK"
```

Everything is good but when i try to put attributes for my textbox doesn't work.
I try this but doesn't work:

```
For i = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1

    Dim Rating_BOX As TextBox = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(i).FindControl("BOX_Rating"), TextBox)
    Rating_BOX.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.value = 'OK';")
    Rating_BOX.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "this.value = 'NOK';")

Next
```

My table is like this:

[image]

I want when a user click into textbox to put ok and when action double click to put NOK but my code doesn't react when i click into textbox.

Comment: does the html render out the attributes?

Comment: use `RowCreated` event for creating dynamically controls.